# PHP artisan migrate exception

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, migrate

I am new to php laravel and got an issue that I cannot solve. Please advise me. When I run '`php artisan migrate`', I get a QueryException saying:

> Could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;)

I have tried adding `extension=php_pdo_mysql.so` to my php.ini because it was not there but it did not work

This is the error message I get:
[QueryException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQkIN.png)

Thanks very much

Comment: Have you configured your database in config/database.php?

Comment: I did not change the file database.php, I left it as is.

Comment: Looks like it's trying to connect to a SQLite database. What is the default connection string in config/database.php?

Comment: it is mysql=> 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),  I tried changing it into sqlite but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ensure you have php7.0-mysql installed.
2. uncomment extension=php_pdo_mysql.so;
3. Ensure you have your database environment variables configured properly to connect to your mysql database.  Something like this in your .env file.

   `DB_CONNECTION=mysql
   DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
   DB_PORT=3306
   DB_DATABASE=database_name
   DB_USERNAME=database_username
   DB_PASSWORD=database_password`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I made the 3 changes you mentioned, but I still have the same error. Do I check something else?

Comment: Can you show me your database environment variables in the .env file?  Also, can you add your mysql details from config/database.php?

Comment: These are the database environment variables in .env:
>DB_CONNECTION=mysql
>DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
>DB_PORT=3306
>DB_DATABASE=database_name
>DB_USERNAME=database_username
>DB_PASSWORD=database_password

Comment: And config/database.php already contains mysql as:
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            ]) : [],
        ],

Comment: Thanks. Now what happens when you login to MySQL with the dB user and password in your .env? Ie run in your command prompt >mysql -u database_username -p database_name

Comment: When I run the command you mentioned I get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'database_username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: Ok so it seems like your issue is that you don’t have the proper credentials in place on your MySQL server. Have you logged in to the dB before?  If so Can you login with your root password?  You then should grant access to the user that you plan on connecting laravel with via a grant command like this > grant all privileges on database_name.* to ‘db_username’@‘%’ identified by ‘db_password’;

Comment: Yes I have logged in to the database before, so I ran the command you provided as:  grant all privileges on database_name.* to ‘database_username’@‘%’ identified by ‘database_password’, but got this error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '%’ identified by ‘database_password’' at line 1

Comment: This should work.  I just ran it against my database.  It's a standard command to grant access.  Please replace the database, user and password with your respective credentials in your .env file.  

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON YourDatabaseName.* TO 'YourUserName'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'YourPassword' WITH GRANT OPTION;

Comment: No worries!  Happy to help.